# Understanding x86 gcc assembly output

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

Pasted below is unoptimized GCC assembly output for "int main(){}".  I'm relatively good with x86 assembly, but some of this is unfamiliar.  Could someone please do a line-by-line walk-through of what's going on here?

```
    .text
.globl _main
_main:
LFB2:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
    leave
    ret
LFE2:
    .section __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
EH_frame1:
    .set L$set$0,LECIE1-LSCIE1
    .long L$set$0
LSCIE1:
    .long   0x0
    .byte   0x1
    .ascii "zR\0"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x78
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x7
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x90
    .byte   0x1
    .align 3
LECIE1:
.globl _main.eh
_main.eh:
LSFDE1:
    .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
    .long L$set$1
LASFDE1:
    .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
    .quad   LFB2-.
    .set L$set$2,LFE2-LFB2
    .quad L$set$2
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$3,LCFI0-LFB2
    .long L$set$3
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x86
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$4,LCFI1-LCFI0
    .long L$set$4
    .byte   0xd
    .byte   0x6
    .align 3
LEFDE1:
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tell the linker to put this into the executable's `.text` section:

```
    .text
```

Export `main` as a external symbol:

```
.globl _main
```

Define the `main` function itself:

```
_main:
LFB2:
```

Save the previous frame pointer:

```
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
```

Set up a new frame pointer:

```
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
```

Restore the old frame pointer and return to caller:

```
    leave
    ret
```

The following directives are setting up an `.eh_frame` section, containing information required by the C++ runtime for exception handling.

```
LFE2:
    .section __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
```

This is the Common Information Entry table:

```
EH_frame1:
```

It starts with a length, calculated from the difference of the `LSCIE1` and `LECIE1` labels:

```
    .set L$set$0,LECIE1-LSCIE1
    .long L$set$0
```

(The `.long`, `.byte`, `.ascii` and `.quad` cause a value of the appropriate type to be directly emitted by the assembler).  Then follows the CIE table itself:

```
LSCIE1:
    .long   0x0
    .byte   0x1
    .ascii "zR\0"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x78
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x7
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x90
    .byte   0x1
    .align 3
LECIE1:
```

Another external symbol, this one for the `main` function's Frame Description Entry (still part of the exception handling information):

```
.globl _main.eh
_main.eh:
```

Again, the FDE starts with a length:

```
LSFDE1:
    .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
    .long L$set$1
```

..and continues with the rest of the FDE table.

```
LASFDE1:
    .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
    .quad   LFB2-.
    .set L$set$2,LFE2-LFB2
    .quad L$set$2
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$3,LCFI0-LFB2
    .long L$set$3
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x86
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$4,LCFI1-LCFI0
    .long L$set$4
    .byte   0xd
    .byte   0x6
    .align 3
LEFDE1:
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

Those exception handling tables are mostly uninteresting, but if you want to know then information on the format is [available here](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/ehframechpt.html).

Comment: Odd that there are C++ features in there.  I produced the output with gcc.

Comment: @kelf: `.eh_frame` stack-unwind metadata is also required for debuggers to backtrace, and for glibc's `backtrace()` function.  It's not *just* for C++.  (`strip` doesn't consider it debug, even for programs built from C source, not C++.)

Answer (score 1):

there are few lines of assembly language. other are definitions (all that start with dot (.)) most of them are memory allocations, other you can easily find in gcc docs.

```
LFB2:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
    leave
    ret
```

this is entering/exiting stack frame.